# how to simulate power off on linux physical machine?

Tags: simulate

already tried:

**reboot**

how to simulate linux power off on Physical machine

like reboot? any other?
`linux`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the easiest way?

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```